# How set custom font to Actionbar Sherlock Tab?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to set font for the "Video" and "Image" tabs in actionbar Sherlok. I have used the following code to do so. It's showing accurately in ICS but not in the lower version device but I have shown accurate output in the other part of this application by stetting TYPE FACE like:

```
a.settypeface("ab.tttf");
a.settext("VIDEO");
```

But how to set typeface in actionbar in this code:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("IMAGE"),
                    AFragment.class, null);

            mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("VIDEO"),
                    BFragment.class, null);
```